# "Захоранивать": есть ли такое слово?

Tags: словообразование

Здравствуйте!
Пожалуйста, помогите образовать форму от слова "захоронить". Предложение такое: "Они продолжают (захоранивать) ядерные отходы на территории Украины".
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существуют  следующие видовые пары для  глагола ХОРОНИТЬ (несов. вид) -  похоронить (нейтр), захоронить (офиц.), схоронить (простор.). При этом основным значением глагола «хоронить»  является  «закапывать в землю, помещать  в гробницу (тело умершего или его  прах  после кремации), обычно с соблюдением принятых обрядов».

В то же время у глагола сов. вида «захоронить» есть собственное значение – «поместить в могильник», и здесь также нужна видовая пара: захоронить – захоранивать или захоронять. У Ожегова предлагается форма «захоронять», однако в современных словарях  мы уже видим  «захоранивать», причем именно этот глагол встречается и в текстах, например:

О том, куда именно захоранивать, спорили пять часов, пока Микоян не прекратил дискуссию.

Эти отходы можно захоранивать и недрах, обеспечив гарантию,

Попытки немецких общественных организаций захоранивать в России останки солдат вермахта, погибших в Великой Отечественной войне, пресекаютсяместными властями.

Пока же даже захоранивать погибших птиц на Тамани ликвидаторам пришлось на свой страх и риск ― их закапывали в карьерах около населённых пунктов.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть сомнения, почему бы не написать так: "Они продолжают хоронить ядерные отходы на территории Украины"? Либо так: "Они продолжают(не прекращают) захоронение ядерных отходов на территории Украины".

Comment: Хоронить ядерные отходы - это употребление слова в неточном значении.
Продолжают захоронение ядерных отходов - книжный стиль, он не всегда подходит к тексту, да и грамматика сложно читается и не везде подходит.

Comment: Вот-вот. Хоронить - это все-таки относится к живым существам, точнее, умершим. А "захоранивать" (или как это правильнее) - к неодушевленным.